# Multi source spring configuration does not save an entity

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I have SpringBoot application which connected to 2 datasource. I need save the same data to 2 differen databases using some logic.

I made 2 very similar sets (configuration, repository and entity). I'm working with Kotlin. So there is 2 configurations : for primary database

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    basePackages = ["org.my.app.repository.primary"],
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "primaryDbEntityManager",
    transactionManagerRef = "primaryDbTransactionManager"
)
class PrimaryConfig {
    @Primary
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.primary-db")
    fun primaryDbDataSource(): DataSource {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create()
            .driverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver")
            .url("jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/primary_db")
            .password("********")
            .username("postgres")
            .build()
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("hibernate.primary-db")
    fun primaryDbEntityManager(): LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean {
        val em = LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean()
        em.dataSource = primaryDbDataSource()
        em.setPackagesToScan("org.my.app.entity.primary")
        val vendorAdapter = HibernateJpaVendorAdapter()
        em.jpaVendorAdapter = vendorAdapter
        val properties = HashMap<String, String?>()
        properties["hibernate.dialect"] = "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"
        properties["hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults"] = "false"
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties)
        return em
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = ["primaryDbTransactionManager"])
    fun primaryDbTransactionManager(): PlatformTransactionManager? {
        val transactionManager = JpaTransactionManager()
        transactionManager.entityManagerFactory = primaryDbEntityManager().getObject()
        return transactionManager
    }
}
```

and for secondary db:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    basePackages = ["org.my.app.repository.secondary"],
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "secondaryDbEntityManager",
    transactionManagerRef = "secondaryDbTransactionManager"
)
class SecondaryConfig {
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.secondary-db")
    fun secondaryDbDataSource(): DataSource {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create()
            .driverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver")
            .url("jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/secondary_db")
            .password("********")
            .username("postgres")
            .build()
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("hibernate.secondary-db")
    fun secondaryDbEntityManager(): LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean {
        val em = LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean()
        em.dataSource = secondaryDbDataSource()
        em.setPackagesToScan("org.my.app.entity.secondary")
        val vendorAdapter = HibernateJpaVendorAdapter()
        em.jpaVendorAdapter = vendorAdapter
        val properties = HashMap<String, String?>()
        properties["hibernate.dialect"] = "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"
        properties["hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults"] = "false"
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties)
        return em
    }

    @Bean(name = ["secondaryDbTransactionManager"])
    fun primaryDbTransactionManager(): PlatformTransactionManager? {
        val transactionManager = JpaTransactionManager()
        transactionManager.entityManagerFactory = secondaryDbEntityManager().getObject()
        return transactionManager
    }
}
```

Repository for primary DB is

```
package org.my.app.repository.primary

@Service
class PrimaryDbRepository(
    @Qualifier("primaryDbEntityManager")
    private val entityManager: EntityManager
) {
    @Transactional
    fun batchInsert(entityList: List<PrimaryEntity>) {
        for (entity in entityList) {
            entityManager.persist(entity)
        }
        entityManager.clear()
    }
}
```

Repository for secondary DB is

```
package org.my.app.repository.secondary

@Service
class SecondaryDbRepository(
    @Qualifier("secondaryDbEntityManager")
    private val entityManager: EntityManager
) {
    @Transactional
    fun batchInsert(entityList: List<SecondaryEntity>) {
        for (entity in entityList) {
            entityManager.persist(entity)
        }
        entityManager.clear()
    }
}
```

Entity for primary DB is

```
package org.my.app.entity.primary

@Entity
@Table(name="table1", schema="public")
data class PrimaryEntity(
    @Id
    val id: Long,
    @Column(name="data_value")
    val dataValue: String?
)
```

Entity for secondaryDB is

```
package org.my.app.entity.secondary

@Entity
@Table(name="table1", schema="public")
data class SecondaryEntity(
    @Id
    val id: Long,
    @Column(name="data_value")
    val dataValue: String?
)
```

I try to save my entities to database in service. I show only one function because exception raised even in this case:

```
@Service
class saver (private val primaryRepository: PrimaryDbRepository, private val secondaryRepository: SecondaryDbRepository) {
  fun saveMyData() {
    val data = listOf(PrimaryEntity(1, "A"), PrimaryEntity(2, "B"))
    primaryRepository.batchInsert(data)

    /* if I leave only "data" save to primary datasource, always works fine*/
    val data2 = listOf(SecondaryEntity(1, "A"), SecondaryEntity(2, "B"))
    secondaryRepository.batchInsert(data2)
  }
}
```

When I call saveMyData I Receive exception ***java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: attempt to create event with null entity*** and ***javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress*** in one call.

The error stack is like

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.checkTransactionNeededForUpdateOperation(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:398) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.checkTransactionNeededForUpdateOperation(SessionImpl.java:3558) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1444) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1440) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_301]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_301]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_301]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_301]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:350) ~[spring-orm-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy103.flush(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_301]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_301]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_301]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_301]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:308) ~[spring-orm-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy103.flush(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.my.app.repository.secondary.SecondaryDbRepository.batchInsert(SecondaryDbRepository.kt:19) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.my.app.repository.secondary.SecondaryDbRepository$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$6c43dc23.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:295) ~[spring-tx-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.my.app.repository.secondary.SecondaryDbRepository$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b30f9725.batchInsert(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.my.app.services.Saver.saveMyData(Saver.kt:18) ~[classes/:na]
...........
```

What I made wrong? Or how can I save my new entities?

Comment: can you please post the whole stacktrace?

Comment: I have never worked on Kotlin but worked on Java and code looks similar but obviously syntax is different. I think entity class names mentioned in repository classes are incorrect. It should be   List<PrimaryEntity> instead of List<PrimaryDataEntity>. Same goes to other repository class

Comment: @SimonMartinelli, I attached meaning part of callstack (hier part is about scheduler to call my function)

Comment: @RohitAgarwal thank you, you are right, I have a mistake with entity naming.

Comment: I Found that error happens only for secondary repository, primary repository saves data correctly

Comment: It fails because you haven't instructed the `@Transactional` which transactiobn manager to use. Hence it will use the primary one for each of them, failing the second because that doesn't have an active transaction for the used `EntityManager`. You need to add the name to the `@Transactional` annotation of which transaction manager to use.

Comment: @M.Deinum thank you a lot. I used javax.transaction.Transactional annotation. It works fine with pointing to certain transactional manager

Answer (score 0):

Using org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional with pointing to certain transaction manager solved the problem.

```
........
@Transactional("secondaryDbTransactionManager")
fun batchInsert(entityList: List<SecondaryEntity>)
........
```